# Android: ProgressDialog failing

Tags: android, progressdialog

I'm having real problems getting a ProgressDialog up and running. My code:

```
ProgressDialog dialog;

try {
  dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
  dialog.setCancelable(true);
  dialog.setMessage("Loading ...");
  // set the progress to be horizontal
  dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
  // set the bar to the default value of 0
  dialog.setProgress(0);

  // set the maximum value
  dialog.setMax(100);
  // display the progressbar
  dialog.show();
 }
catch (Exception e1)
 {
   e1.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Below that I create my background thread to load some stuff and update the progress bar, but it never gets that far. In the stack trace I get "Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application", but the dialog seems (in the debugger) to have all the right things, it isn't null, but I'm getting this error.

Can anyone shine a light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What kind of context are you using to create the ProgressDialog?

I think that the ProgressDialog want work with a ApplicationContext. The API is not very correct the constructor should request an Activity instead of a Context.

Try to pass a reference to a Activity to the constructor instead of an regular Context.

Instead of using:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
```

use

```
Context context = this;
```

Or if you are in an inner class of your Activity (a listener, or Task) use:

```
Context context = MyActivityNameComesHere.this;
```

See my [Issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?thanks=19360&ts=1313674059) in the Android Bugtracker about this.

Comment: Sorry @Janusz I'm (noob) not sure what you mean. The context I'm passing does come from: Context context = getApplicationContext(); - I'm not sure what you mean by passing a reference to an activity. Could you give me a line of code to show what you mean? Many thanks.

Comment: +1 Using getApplicationContext() will cause FCs when displaying dialogs

Comment: Excellent, thank you, it works. However, my dialog still doesn't appear - a crash about 3 lines later kills everything, but you answered my question! (I may be back regarding my later crash :/).