# Android: ProgressDialog failing, Version 2

Tags: android, progressdialog

I asked a similar Q to this before but I'm still in trouble. ProgressDialog is causing me severe hair loss. This code has a progressdialog (spinner) just to see if I can make one appear - which just causes a 10 second delay before I then go and open my file.

I have a listactivity. The user selects a file, which brings us here:

```
private void openFile(File f) {
    Global.iDelay = 0;

    // Create an Intent
    Global.file = f;

    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(viewer2.this, "", "Loading...");
    dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    dialog.show(); // dialog does not appear //

    // create a thread for counting the sleep seconds
    Thread background = new Thread (new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           try {

              while (Global.iDelay < 10) {
                   // wait between each update
                   Thread.sleep(1000);

                   Log.d("Baz","iDelay = "+Global.iDelay);

                   // active the update handler
                   progressHandler.sendMessage(progressHandler.obtainMessage());
                   }

           } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException e) {
               // if something fails do something smart
           }
       }
    });

    // start the background thread
    background.start();

    dialog.dismiss();

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    // then I go and prepare for my file and open it        


    Global.PrepareForGL (this); 

    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, ShowGL.class);
    this.startActivity(myIntent1);
    }
```

My handler is defined like this:

```
//handler for the background updating
public static Handler progressHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Global.iDelay++;
    }
};
```

My problem: The timer thread starts and suire enough counts off 10 seconds (my log.d gives me a count to 10), but no dialog appears. However, during the 10 second count I am already executing the 'prepareforgl' method, which I understood would not happen until the background thread has completed and the dialog been dismissed. I know this because that also contains a log.d line which gives me a result between the 5 and 6 second counters.

My Questions: Is it relevant that I'm doing this in a listactivity? Where is my dialog? Am I right in thinking the entire background thread should have executed before I then carry on with my work?

Any light you can shed on progressdialogs would be very welcome. Many thanks.

Baz.

Comment: Using AsyncTask instead of Thread/Handler to take care of background work will go a long way in simplifying the process.

Answer (score 2):

You are starting your background thread and then dismissing the dialog.  So, you aren't actually delaying the call to dismiss the dialog.  It might just be happening too fast for you to ever see it.

Your code would be much cleaner if you use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to do this.  Put the delay in the `doInBackground` method, and the dialog dismissal in `onPostExecute`.

Also, you are mixing the static call to create and show the dialog with other calls to change and re-display the dialog.  Try this instead:

```
dialog = new ProgressDialog(viewer2.this);
dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.show();
```

Comment: (and Tim) My original need was simply a progress dialog to give the user something to look at while I load a biggish file (5-20 seconds work). The file loads, the bar progresses (or the spinner spins) and then the new activity displays the file. Am I really in need of an asynctask or do I just need to make a progressdialog work? Many thanks. ps, a progress bar would be best but even a working spinner would be good.

Comment: How is openFile getting invoked?  Is it inside your ListActivity?  Is openFile running on the UI thread when it gets called?

Comment: Yes, openfile is a method directly inside the ListActivity (I got the bulk of a file browser here: [link](http://www.anddev.org/android_filebrowser__v20-t101.html). The entire view is the listactivity and selecting an item in the list (a file name) drops straight onto openFile. I have read all of the progressdialog posts here and elsewhere and had a helpful answer here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107991/android-progressdialog-failing) but the activity vs context api bug isn't the issue and my code has all been rewritten since then.

Comment: I've added something else for you to try.  Like I said earlier, your current code does not cause a delay before dismissing the dialog.  You need to fix that to introduce the delay and see the dialog.

Comment: Ahah, the 'new ProgressDialog' helps - the dialog appears! Thank you. But putting my file-load code in place of the timer isn't right. I thought the code in the Runnable block was ALL run before exiting and then the dialog is dismissed, but it seems to START loading the file and then immediately execute the following code, which fails because the file isn't all loaded yet...

Comment: I'm probably not being clear :( What I really want to do is this    1. Make a spinner dialog box, 2. show the box, 3. start loading the file, 4. complete loading the file, 5. dismiss the box, 6. execute following code, so the dialog is basically just something for the user to see while I go and do something time consuming.